# Monaco Editor showing character on empty line

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, monaco-editor

My Problem is that whenever I start a new line in the monaco editor, it shows the character Â, but I can't select it and it disappears as soon as i start to write something and appears again if I empty the line.

I have already tried to find where this character could come from within the code I am working with but with no success (it is a larger project that was started by someone else and the bug was already there from the moment I started working on it). I tried looking into the API of the monaco editor to find some sort of clue where this bug might originate from but also with no success. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has an idea where else I should look I would appreciate it very much.

I am sorry for not including code or a minimal, reproducable example but I really don't know how to reproduce it since I don't know what changes even triggered it in the first place.

An example of the output of the monaco editor:

int i = 0

Â

function f(){

Â

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an encoding problem. It's probably interpreting `&nbsp;` as Â. I think you're in ISO-8859-1 and want to be in UTF-8, so put this at the top of the HTML: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Edit: Another thing that might work is simply copying their code, pasting it into an editor, changing the encoding to UTF-8, then copy-pasting it back into the original file.

Comment: Thanks, the addition of the html tag solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

See https://www.diycode.cc/projects/Microsoft/monaco-editor

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="controls/monaco/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>
<script>
    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'controls/monaco' }});
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
        var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: [
                'function x() {',
                '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
                '}'
            ].join('\n'),
            language: 'javascript'
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```